# Laravel use row span to mirge rows for every name and get total under every name

Tags: php, laravel

Sorry for my bad language, I want to show only the name without duplicate and show the rows related to this name, one of these columns is for amount so I need also to show the total of the amount for every name, please check the image which will descripe exactly what I want
Here what I have:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wltmo.jpg
and I want it to be like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUzzf.jpg

Model:

```php
public function getTotalBusers($New,$Old)
{
    return $this
        ->leftJoin('users', $this->table.'.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select($this->table.'.*', 'users.name as buser_name')
        ->where('users.role_id','!=',0)
        ->where('users.role_id','!=',1)
        ->whereBetween('reportdate',[$New,$Old])
        ->orderBy($this->table.'.user_id','desc')
        ->get();
}
```

User:

```
   protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'username','role_id', 'password',
    ];
```

Blade:

```html
       <thead>                    
                    <th >Name</th>

                    <th >Amount</th>

                   <th>Given By</th> 
      </thead>

@foreach($allbusers as $key => $allbuser)

    <tr>
 <td>
{{$allbuser->buser_name}}
</td>

<td>
    {{$allbuser->amount}}
</td>

<td>
{{$allbuser->waiter_name}}
</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This can be achieved with Eloquent relationships. Can you provide the models?

Comment: allredy provided!!

Comment: User and AllBuser?

Comment: in User model I have the default records also role_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
# Buser Model
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

# User Model
public function busers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Buser::class, 'user_id');
}
```

```php
# Controller
$allbusers = User::select('id', 'name')
->whereNotIn('role_id', [0, 1])
->whereHas('busers', function ($query) use ($New, $Old) {
    $query->whereBetween('reportdate', [$New, $Old]);
})
->with(['busers' => function ($query) use ($New, $Old) {
    $query->whereBetween('reportdate', [$New, $Old]);
}])
->orderBy('user.id', 'desc')
->get();
```

```xml
# View
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Given By</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($allbusers as $user)
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="{{ $user->busers->count() + 1 }}">{{ $user->name }}</td>
      </tr>
      @foreach($user->busers as $buser)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $buser->amount }}</td>
          <td>{{ $buser->waiter_name }}</td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
      <tr>
        <td>TOTAL</td>
        <td>{{ $user->busers->sum('amount') }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I forgot a `get()`

Comment: I added get before but also the result are zero!!

Comment: Need to add the id to the select